# Why is the output of my code different when I input the variables of a class?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm currently learning about classes and I'm stuck on this problem that requires me to find if two rectangles overlap. Here is my code:

```
class Point:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

def overlap(l1, r1, l2, r2):
    if r1.x <= l1.x or l1.y <= r1.y or r2.x <= l2.x or l2.y <= r2.y:
       print("Invalid")
    elif l1.x >= r2.x or l2.x >= r1.x:
       print("Does not intersect")
    elif l1.y <= r2.y or l2.y <= r1.y:
       print("Does not intersect")
    elif l1.x == l2.x and l1. y == l2.y and r1.x == r2.x and r1.y == r2.y:
       print("They're the same")
    else:
       print("Intersects")
```

This is the code to find whether the two rectangles overlap or not. But that's not really my problem, my problem is when I input the variables, the output is wrong. When I do it like this:

```
l1 = Point(0, 5)
r1 = Point(3, 10)
l2 = Point(0, 6)
r2 = Point(3, 2)

overlap(l1, r1, l2, r2)
>>> Invalid
```

The answer is correct. But when I input the same variables like this:

```
l1 = Point(input(), input())
r1 = Point(input(), input())
l2 = Point(input(), input())
r2 = Point(input(), input())

overlap(l1, r1, l2, r2)
>>> Intersects
```

The answer is different. I don't know what's wrong. Can anyone help me figure out how to correct this code? And if there are suggestions to improve my code to find whether the two rectangles overlap, please tell me. Thank you.

Comment: Cast it to int.

Comment: Perhaps `input()` results in a different value (like a string), and that cannot be used for size comparisons, so it results in the last option.

Comment: There's [python - How can I read inputs as numbers? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers) which has pretty detailed explanation, but it isn't the same question.

Comment: From the question, floats are also possible variables. Should I cast it to a float instead?

Comment: floats works as numeric value types, so that's one you should try.

Comment: Thank you guys. I used float and it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your problem is basically that `'3' <= '10'` is `False`.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yep, I figured it out. I had to cast it into a float. Thanks!

Comment: Please either mark the question as duplicate or accept an answer, whichever helped you most. So the question doesn't stay opened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` returns a string. Try the following in the interactive interpreter:

```py
print("e" <= "r")
```

It will give `True`.
EDIT:
It seems, python converts the letters to numbers based on the ascii table or whatever, and so "r" <= "r" is still True, but "s" <= "r" will be False.

When using `input`, you are comparing strings, which will give True, as you saw above. Replace `input()` with `int(input())` or `float(input())`, and it should work.

Comment: @superbrain i DID of course try it myself, it was just to show the OP what it does

Comment: @superbrain ok thanks, it was a typo !

Comment: @superbrain why did you remove your comment ?

Comment: Thanks! I casted it into a float and it worked.

Comment: @frederic Because your edit made them obsolete.